# Register notification in iOS 9

Tags: apple-push-notifications, swift2, ios9

I am using this to register notification :

```
if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
                let types:UIUserNotificationType = (.Alert | .Badge | .Sound)
                let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)

                application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
                application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

            } else {
                // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
                application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(.Alert | .Badge | .Sound)
            }
```

But it's not woking for iOS 9.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found solution :

```
 if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            let types:UIUserNotificationType = ([.Alert, .Sound, .Badge])
            let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes([.Alert, .Sound, .Badge])
        }
    }
    else {
        // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes([.Alert, .Sound, .Badge])
    }
```

The above code is working perfectly for me .